# Callback in parent component when all nested child custom elements have been attached to DOM?

Tags: aurelia

I have added a component `componentA` to my view. It is composed of `componentA.js` and `componentA.html`. Now `componentA.html` contains two custom elements `customElement1` and `customElement2`. Additaionlly, `customElement1` also contains a custom element `customElement1-1`.

### componentA.html

```
<template>
    <require from="..."></require
    <require from="..."></require

    <customElement1></customElement1>
    <customElement2></customElement2>
</template>
```

### customElement1.html

```
<template>
    <require from="..."></require>

    <customElement1-1></customElement1-1>
</template>
```

Adding the `activate` hook to these custom element produces the following output:

```
componentA - activate
customElement1 - activate
customElement1-1 - activate
customElement2 - activate
---
Need to call componentA here, but all custom elements have to be attached to DOM
```

Is there an additional hook that can be called from `componentA` when all of the nested custom elements have been attached to the DOM?

Comment: In short - no. This GitHub issue talks about a similar problem though, and might help; https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/132.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution using `TaskQueue`. See [this post](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/02/working-with-the-aurelia-task-queue/) for more info

> A microtask allows you defer a task to be executed on the next event
>   loop or tick. When you queue a microtask you are scheduling for that
>   particular task to execute immediately after the currently executing
>   script.

### componentA.js

```
import {TaskQueue} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(TaskQueue)

export class ComponentA {
    constructor(TaskQueue) {
        this.tq = TaskQueue;
    }

    attached() {
        this.tq.queueMicroTask(() => {
            console.log('Hello world');
        });
    }
}
```

By adding the code above the following output is produced:

```
componentA - activate
customElement1 - activate
customElement1-1 - activate
customElement2 - activate
componentA - Hello world
```

Comment: Interesting! That's pretty clever - are the components always going to be attached during the current execution loop though? Or is this akin to a setTimeout, where you're hoping things are attached by then?

Comment: From my understanding the `queueMicroTask` method adds a task to the end of the queue where any `activate`, etc ... hooks from nested components or elements are already in the queue. However, I am not quite sure. Thats why I was hoping that someone can confirm this solution so I can accept the answer.